# How do i stop my bluetooth mouse from disconnecting after a while? [UBUNTU 18.10]

Tags: wireless, mouse, bluetooth, atheros, 18.10

**Hi! I'm quite new to Linux's world, so don't blame me if i don't give something for granted :D**

My bluetooth mouse works fine, just as expected; but after a while i'm not using it (e.g. when i watch a video), it just disconnectes automatically.
I'm wondering if there's any way to increase this timeout, or to completely remove this option